# Reflect the value based on the specific row of selected appended items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append

I have an issue in which I am trying to capture the value of an `input type` element on `keyup` and then reflect that value in a `span` which is the total amount of the item. I have my snippet but when I try to handle the `keyup` event on the input type it changes the value of the total for all selected items; I just want to change the value of the total for the row in which the `keyup` event was triggered and to be able to remove the specific row based on the click of the `remove item button`. Did I miss something? How can I get the specific row? Can anybody help me with this?

```js
$("#allcb").change(function () {
  $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop(
    "checked",
    $(this).prop("checked")
  );
});

$(document).on( "keyup",  ".quantity_input",function() {
  var value_input = 0;
  var price_value = 0;
  var total_value = 0;

  value_input = $(".quantity_input").val();
  price_value = $(".price_value").html();
  total_value = parseInt(value_input) * parseInt(price_value);
  $(".total_value_row").text(total_value);
});

$(document).on("click",".remove_data" , function(){
        alert("I've been clicked! remove the row item");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#add_data").click(function () {
    var grid = document.getElementById("Table1");
    var message = "Values                 Description\n";

    var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    var str = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      if (
        checkBoxes[i].checked &&
        checkBoxes[i].name !== "allcb" &&
        !checkBoxes[i].hasCovered
      ) {
        var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        str +=
          '<div class="row" ><div class="col-md-8"><p class="me-3"> ' +
          '<a href="#" class="text-body">' +
          '<button type="button" class = "remove_data" id="remove_data">Remove item</button></a>&nbsp' +

          '<span>Quantity</span>&nbsp' +
          row.cells[2].innerHTML +
          "</a></p> " +
          '<span class="me-1">Price </span>&nbsp' +
          '<span class="me-1 price_value">' +
          row.cells[1].innerHTML +
          "</span>&nbsp" +
          '<input type="number" id="quantity_input" class="form-control form-control-sm w-px-75 quantity_input" value="1" min="1" max="5"/>&nbsp'+
          '<span class= "total_value_row" >total value is</span> '+
          "</div></div><hr>";
          checkBoxes[i].hasCovered = true;
        }
      }
      $(".whole-div-class").append(str);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="Table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" id="allcb" name="allcb" />
      </th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" />
      </td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td> 25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" />
      </td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb3" />
      </td>
      <td>400</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<button type="button" id="add_data">Add data</button>
<hr>

<div class="row whole-div-class"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is a `keyup` event on an `.quantity_input` element, we want only the state of the values in the element's row to change. To achieve this, we need to *scope* the effects of our state manipulation to the `.row` that contains the element. We can get the the `.row` by using jQuery's [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method and then passing the result to all of the jQuery selector calls in the handler so that the result set will always be constrained to the `.row`.

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".quantity_input", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var value_input = 0;
  var price_value = 0;
  var total_value = 0;

  value_input = $(".quantity_input", $row).val();
  price_value = $(".price_value", $row).html();
  total_value = parseInt(value_input) * parseInt(price_value);
  $(".total_value_row", $row).text(total_value);
});
```

We can take the same approach for the remove handler. Get the `.row` that is closest to the clicked `.remove_data` button and call jQuery's [.remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) on it.

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove_data", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  
  $row.remove();
});
```

Note: I would also recommend moving the `<hr>` that you have as a sibling of `.row` to be contained by `.row`, so that you don't get a bunch of `<hr>` elements remaining as you remove each `.row`.

In order to reset the checkbox that corresponds to the row that was removed, we would need a way to get the checkbox that corresponds to the row. One way to do this would be with a data-attribute. We could set a data-attribute on each row containing the name of its associated checkbox. Then, when the row is removed, we can use that data-attribute to get the checkbox, uncheck it, and set its `hasCovered` property to `false`.

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove_data", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var checkboxName = $row.data('for');
  var $checkbox = $(`input[type="checkbox"][name="${checkboxName}"]`);
  
  $row.remove();
  $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
  $checkbox.get(0).hasCovered = false;
});
```

The full code example becomes:

```js
$("#allcb").change(function() {
  $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop(
    "checked",
    $(this).prop("checked")
  );
});

$(document).on("keyup", ".quantity_input", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var value_input = 0;
  var price_value = 0;
  var total_value = 0;

  value_input = $(".quantity_input", $row).val();
  price_value = $(".price_value", $row).html();
  total_value = parseInt(value_input) * parseInt(price_value);
  $(".total_value_row", $row).text(total_value);
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove_data", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var checkboxName = $row.data('for');
  var $checkbox = $(`input[type="checkbox"][name="${checkboxName}"]`);
  
  $row.remove();
  $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
  $checkbox.get(0).hasCovered = false;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_data").click(function() {
    var grid = document.getElementById("Table1");
    var message = "Values                 Description\n";

    var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    var str = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      if (
        checkBoxes[i].checked &&
        checkBoxes[i].name !== "allcb" &&
        !checkBoxes[i].hasCovered
      ) {
        var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        str +=
          '<div class="row" data-for="' + checkBoxes[i].id + '"><div class="col-md-8"><p class="me-3"> ' +
          '<a href="#" class="text-body">' +
          '<button type="button" class = "remove_data" id="remove_data">Remove item</button></a>&nbsp' +

          '<span>Quantity</span>&nbsp' +
          row.cells[2].innerHTML +
          "</a></p> " +
          '<span class="me-1">Price </span>&nbsp' +
          '<span class="me-1 price_value">' +
          row.cells[1].innerHTML +
          "</span>&nbsp" +
          '<input type="number" id="quantity_input" class="form-control form-control-sm w-px-75 quantity_input" value="1" min="1" max="5"/>&nbsp' +
          '<span class= "total_value_row" >total value is</span> ' +
          "</div><hr></div>";
        checkBoxes[i].hasCovered = true;
      }
    }
    $(".whole-div-class").append(str);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="Table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" id="allcb" name="allcb" />
      </th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" />
      </td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td> 25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" />
      </td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb3" />
      </td>
      <td>400</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<button type="button" id="add_data">Add data</button>
<hr>

<div class="row whole-div-class"></div>
```

Comment: thanks it's almost there, but it seems it affect the Item when I tried to remove everything/every item when I add it back again it didn't reflect at all, did I miss out something? when appending the data?

Comment: @BootCamp: I have updated my post with an explanation of how to reset the checkbox when its corresponding row has been removed.